# getting error while try to ignore zero at the begining of phonenumber?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, authentication

```java
//getting data
String _phoneNumber = number.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
String _password = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

if (_phoneNumber.charAt(0) == '0') {
    _phoneNumber = _phoneNumber.substring(1);
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
```

Comment: probably because the string you're passing in is empty

Comment: Also u check for char '0' like charAt(0)='0' not with number 0 cause no character has an ASCII value of 0

Comment: i run the app and try to login without passing any data to check the validation, when i click login it give me this error

Comment: @Syncit i try it but error still same

Comment: Then it's what @a_local_nobody suggested , your string is empty look at the bottom of your stack trace it clearly specifies java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0. Length of your string is 0

Comment: are you sure about _phoneNumber is not null. You should put an if statement for null check. Such as if (_phoneNumbar !=  null && _phoneNumber.length !=0  ) so you can  be sure if it is null

Comment: If _phoneNumber would have been null, there would not have been a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (but a NullPointerException instead). It is what @a_local_nobody suggested from the beginning.

Comment: But your if statement would catch both null and the empty String @fatmazehragüç.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your string is not an empty string. You may be interested in using the `startsWith()` method instead of `charAt()`:

```
String _phoneNumber = number.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
String _password = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

if (_phoneNumber.length > 0 && _phoneNumber.startsWith('0')) {
    _phoneNumber = _phoneNumber.substring(1);
}
```

Here is a link to the `startsWith()` docs, if you're interested: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String#startsWith(java.lang.String)